# how to disable magic quotes using go daddy server?

Tags: php

I am hosting my site with go daddy and I am trying to disable magic quotes because at the moment i am getting text in my mysql table showing as `jame'/s` rather than just `jame's`.

I have tried doing this in `.htaccess` by adding:

```
'php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off'
```

But this causes a 505 error.

I have tried to do `php.ini` and added:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off;
magic_quotes_runtime = Off;
magic_quotes_sybase = Off;
```

And I have tried doing `php5.ini` with:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off;
```

Nothing is working for me and I'm still getting a `\` where every `'` should be. Why is it displayed like that? What can I do to get rid of `\`.

Comment: i should also mention that i am already using stripslashes in my html but this alone is not enough

Comment: Have you restarted the web-server after changing php.ini? Also, what does `phpinfo();` show you for `magic_quotes_gpc`?

Comment: what version of PHP are you using? magic quotes should default to being off anyway in any recent PHP version.

Comment: Show us what phpinfo give you.

Comment: Could you possibly ask your web host to fix this?

Answer (score 7):

.htaccess won't work in shared hosting.Just try the following steps.

A) Create a file named **php5.ini** and keep in the root folder, Add the following lines in it

**magic_quotes_gpc = Off;
magic_quotes_runtime = Off;
magic_quotes_sybase = Off;**

B) A PHP initialization file is not always immediately recognized by the server. After making the changes to your php5.ini file, you may need to use the following steps to force the updates to go through:

1. Log in to your Account Manager.
2. Click Web Hosting.
3. Next to the hosting account you want to use, click Launch.
4. In the Stats & Monitors section of the hosting Control Panel, click the System Processes icon.
5. Click End Web and follow any prompts.
6. Reload the phpinfo.php page to see if the desired changes have taken effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the php value into the PHP itself :

```
//At the beginning of the page
ini_set('magic_quotes_gpc', 'Off'); //Magic quotes for incoming GET/POST/Cookie data.
ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', 'Off'); //Magic quotes for runtime-generated data, e.g. data from SQL, from exec(), etc.
ini_set('magic_quotes_sybase', 'Off'); //Use Sybase-style magic quotes (escape ' with '' instead of \').
```

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/fr/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)

Answer (score 0):

To turn off the magic quotes try this:

```
ini_set('magic_quotes_gpc', 'Off');
```

But I advice you to put this in `.htaccess` to turn off for the full website implementation

```
php_value magic_quotes_gpc off
```

Comment: if i place that code in the .htaccess file i get an internal service error on page load.

Comment: due to windows and unix file format. Kindly upload the unix file format file to do things

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue for me:

http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/error-installing-joomla-3-0-magic-quotes-gpc-off/

Edit php5.ini in the webroot folder and add this to bottom.

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
zend_extension=/usr/local/php53/lib/php/extensions/ioncube.so
zend_extension=/usr/local/php53/lib/php/extensions/ZendOptimizer.so
```

Make sure you put it at the end, it won't work at the beginning.

End web processes by following these steps (makes sure that the new php configuration is loaded
 http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5647/why-isnt-my-phpini-file-taking-effect

Answer (score 0):

Please note that if your hosting include many websites, you just need upload php5.ini to your root hosting folder (not root of website). I have try and get success now.

Incase you are not success to turn magic_quotes_gpc off, please feel free to contact me by skype at boducoscar. I have searching and test nearly 1 day for only turn this off, so i know how disappointed you are in this problem :)

php5.ini code:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```